# How to cleanup /usr/lib/modules and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, kernel

I executed the command apt autoremove but those folders persist.

As the command "du -h -x --max-depth=1 /usr/lib | sort -hr | head -n 10" showed me, they are currently using almost 1G each:

```
858M    /usr/lib/modules
823M    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

How can i cleanup this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I needed to do this, as with over a year of using Linux on a Chromebook, /usr/lib/modules was taking over 10GiB of disk space (which is at a premium on this device) and I am only ever going to be running a single kernel instance anyway. The disk space *necessary* to run a single kernel was only ~500MiB, for contrast, ~5% of the disk space actually being used.

I came up with a solution myself, based on my distribution (KDE Neon, Ubuntu LTS-based), which consists of multiple Bash commands to do the following:

- Detect the currently running Linux version
- Detect `linux-modules-*` packages that belong to Linux versions *not* currently running
- Uninstall all `linux-modules-*` packages (and depending `linux-image-*` packages) which are not running

Note that I've only tested this *when already running* the latest Linux kernel installed on my distribution. Your distribution might come with packages that depend on a meta-package, such as `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS-based distributions, and I haven't tested this script when running an older Linux after installing a newer one.

## TL;DR:

```bash
sudo apt remove $(dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*' | cut -f1 | grep -v "$(uname -r)")
```

## OK, But What Does That Mean?

The first command to run is `uname -r`. This prints the release number of your currently-running Linux kernel, in a format such as this:

```bash
$ uname -r
5.15.0-48-generic
```

Find out more at [`man uname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname).

The second command to look at is `dpkg-query`, which lets us query installed packages in different ways. You can use `--list` for a pretty, interactive display, but I chose to use `--show` to make scripting simpler.

```bash
$ dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*'
linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic 5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2
linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic 5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1
# etc.
```

Find out more at [`man dpkg-query`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg-query).

A determined reader could probably figure out how to use the `--showformat` option to skip this step, but I preferred a more familiar approach - the `cut` command. The `cut` command simply takes standard input, an optional delimiter provided with `-d` (a tabulator character by default), and a field argument provided with `-f`. In this case, it takes the output of our `dpkg-query` command and returns the first column:

```bash
$ dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*' | cut -f1
linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic
linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic
# etc.
```

Find out more at [`man cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

We pipe the output of *that* into the `grep` command, which lets us select lines that match a certain pattern - or, in this case, lines that *don't* match a certain pattern, using the `-v|--invert-match` option. The `"$(uname -r)"` returns a line like `5.15.0-48-generic`, which is then used as the pattern to `grep`. This is how we select all `linux-modules` packages which are *not* currently running.

```bash
$ dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*' | cut -f1 | grep -v "$(uname -r)"
# = dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*' | cut -f1 | grep -v "5.15.0-48-generic"
linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic
linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic
# etc.
```

Find out more at [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Finally, we just use this list as arguments to the `sudo apt remove` command, which is probably so familiar to people at this point it doesn't need much explanation:

```bash
$ sudo apt remove $(dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*' | cut -f1 | grep -v "$(uname -r)")
# = sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic [...]
```

... but in case those are *not* familiar to you, [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) allows you to run a command as root, the system administrator (or theoretically another user), which is necessary to use [`man apt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html), which manages packages and dependencies on Debian (hence Ubuntu)-based distributions.

Comment: Thank you! This freed about 13GiB of space from my /usr/lib/modules directory 

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you very much. I have a question: in my case I have a Debian 11 distro (`uname -r` shows `5.10.0-19-amd64`) and `dpkg-query` command doesn't return `linux-modules-*` but `linux-images-*`. Would it be correct to run the same command but querying with `linux-images-*`?

Comment: Hello @AlvaroPedraza, sorry for not responding sooner. You should check the output of both `dpkg-query --show 'linux-modules-*'` and `uname -r` on their own. If `uname -r` has the same pattern as the package names, it should work, yes. Be very careful running a command like this: I would suggest looking up the latest installed linux-images package and, after running the command, performing `sudo apt install [package]` just to be safe.

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza I can confirm (on Debian 12) that running `apt-get purge linux-modules-6.1.0-12-amd64` removed the `/usr/lib/modules/6.1.0-12-amd64` directory as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to empty /usr/lib and come up with one approach:

```
apt-show-versions |grep "No available version in archive"
```

will show the packages that are not currently provided by any sources.list (for this Ubuntu version). It includes e.g. manually installed packages from previous Ubuntu versions, if you have been doing upgrades. The issue is, that there are also packages that I wanted keep such as slack, draw.io etc., so you need to manually inspect the packages you don't need anymore.

If you find a pattern from the packages that you definately want to delete, such as Ubuntu 16.04 packages on Ubuntu 22.04, you can run:

```
apt-show-versions |grep "No available version in archive" |grep 16.04 |cut -d " " -f1 |xargs apt remove --purge
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply put: *Don't*.

Theoretically you could delete modules that's not needed on the machine you're on, but if you do a wrong step somewhere, you risk the machine not booting any more. And you'd have to repeat it for every kernel update.

It's a gigabyte. Disk is cheap. Live with it.

Comment: Yeah, for distros running on Raspberry PI and other similar tech that can not have extended disks, only limited SD Cards and similar disks, "Live with it" is not a option.

Comment: It is. Modern RPi's support USB drives just fine, and SD cards is available in the hundreds of gigabytes. Furthermore, this site is about ***business system managament***, not your pet Pi at home. Answers here may differ from answers on Ask Ubuntu or Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: Not in Brazil with it's economy system and tech prices flying above the sky. Pls, have a little empathy... "Just buy new bigger tech" is'nt a solution :| We need to do more with less $. But thanks anyway, @Marcus Harrison solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @RaulChiarella That's rather far from best practice. I'd argue that your approach may fly at Unix.SE or Askubuntu, but it's simply not relevant on a business focused site - for above mentioned reasons. Manual cruft like this will come back to haunt you some day.